# How I can convert concrete syntax values to other kinds of values?

Tags: rascal, concrete-syntax-tree

Given some concrete syntax value, how I can I map it to a different type of value (in this case an `int`)?

```
// Syntax
start syntax MyTree = \node: "(" MyTree left "," MyTree right ")"
                    | leaf: Leaf leaf
                    ;

layout MyLayout = [\ \t\n\r]*;

lexical Leaf = [0-9]+;
```

This does not work unfortunately:

```
public Tree increment() {
    MyTree tree = (MyTree)`(3, (1, 10))`;

    return visit(tree) {
      case l:(Leaf)`3` => l + 1  
    };
}
```

Or is the only way to `implode` into an ADT where I specified the types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has different possible answers:

1. using `implode` you can convert a parse tree to an abstract tree. If the constructors of the target abstract language expect `int`, then lexical trees which happen to match `[0-9]+` will be automatically converted. For example the syntax tree for `syntax Exp = intValue: IntValue;` could be converted to constructor `data Exp = intValue(int i);` and it will actually build an `i`.
2. in general to convert one type of values to another in Rascal you write (mutually) recursive functions, as in `int eval (MyTree t)` and `int (Leaf l)`.
3. if you want to actually increment the syntactic representation of a Leaf value, you have to convert back (parse or via a concrete pattern) from the resulting `int` back to the `Leaf`.

Example:

```
import String;
MyTree increment() {
    MyTree tree = (MyTree)`(3, (1, 10))`;

    return visit(tree) {
      case Leaf l => [Leaf] "<toInt("<l>") + 1>";  
    };
}
```

First the lexical is converted to a string `"<l>"`, this is then parsed as an `int` using `toInt()` and we add 1 using `+ 1` and then map the `int` back to a string `"< ... >"`, after which we can call the `Leaf` parser using `[Leaf]`.